# Content Type - Folders

Tags: content-type

I added a custom content type with the Folder parent, then added columns to display when adding that custom content type; however, the custom content type shows up under "New Document" and none of the columns I added show up. I'm very confused. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

add the columns to that view then it will visible to you,listsettings-->scrolldown you will find "Views" [image]